# WordPress multilingual search form with polylang

Tags: wordpress, search, multilingual, search-form, polylang

I created a multi-language presentation site using polylang plugin. I am very happy with this plugin, except the way it handles the search form. 
When i try to search anything, the menu disappears and it doesn't search in the desired language .

Answer (score 2):

i managed to resolve my problem by following the next steps:

I created a file searchform.php and entered the following code:

```
// the . 'index.php/' part is not mandatory, my website works like this. you can try without it
<form method="get" class="search-form form-inline" id="searchform"
      action="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/') . 'index.php/' . pll_current_language() . '/'); ?>">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="search-field form-control" name="s" id="s" placeholder="<?php pll_e('Search'); ?>"/>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="submit" class="search-submit btn btn-default"><?php pll_e('Search'); ?></button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

if the code `<?php get_search_form(); ?>` doesn't display your custom form, you can always use:

```
  <?php get_template_part('searchform'); ?>
```